Perfview using Stack Trace for App Insight/ASP.NET Core Web APIs
I am new to performance in general and have been learning Perfview.
I was curious how to go about using PerfView to test the performance of my APIs hosted on ASP.NET Core Web APIs?
I was wondering if I could use the profiler that picks up the stack trace on App Insight and just have it read the information there to drill it down and solve any performance issues.
Or is it better to get on the actual server itself where it is hosted and run the API endpoints?

To analyze the performance of the ASP .NET Core Web APIs use PerfView. It provides valuable insights into the application's behavior and help identify performance bottlenecks.


Launch PerfView and start a performance profiling session. You can do this by selecting "Collect" from the main menu and choosing the appropriate profiling mode based on the scenario. For analyzing ASP .NET Core Web APIs, you might want to use the "CPU Sampling" mode initially to get an overview of where the application is spending its time.


Data Capture:

Open Perfview.

Go to Collect and select Collect option as shown below:

Expand the Advanced Options.

Enable the Thread Time and IIS providers. (This will help us give some additional Information while troubleshooting) Note: IIS provider is needed if the app is hosted on IIS. Else you can skip it. This provider can be used only if the IIS Tracing feature is installed.


Status:


I was wondering if I could use the profiler that picks up the stack trace on App Insight and just have it read the information there to drill it down and solve any performance issues.


Regarding your question about using the profiler in Application Insights to pick up stack traces, while Application Insights provides valuable telemetry data and insights into the behavior of the application, PerfView operates at a lower level and directly analyzes the performance of the application on the machine it's running on. While you can certainly use both tools in conjunction, PerfView's focus is more on system-level performance analysis.

Conclusion:
Using PerfView to analyze the performance of your ASP .NET Core Web APIs can complement the insights provided by Application Insights and help you diagnose and optimize performance issues effectively.

thanks for the message! When I try to download the stack trace from the application insight profiler, it just crashes when trying to open it. How can I view my stack traces collected from App insight Profiler?

There would be a problem with your application because, there will be no crashing while checking with the profiler. please check my latest answer for more insights.
